# Group string element by sub string elements

Tags: python, list

I got a list like that made of 50k+ elements:
`string = ['AA.a','aa.b','AS.a','we.b','kk.f']`

The goal is to create many sub string as the number of the sub strings `['.a','.b','.f']` using vectorized style.

I'm moving in this way but is relatively slow:

```
fileL = f.read().split(' ')  #read file for load the **string** as above described
mm = re.compile("\.\w+")
sst = []
for x in range(len(fileL)):
   try:
      xx = mm.findall(fileL[x])[0]
   except:
      xx = ''
   if xx not in sst:
      sst.append(xx) 
for i in sst:
    stt = [x for x in fileL if i in x]
```

Answer (score 0):

If order is not important, you can use a set to collect the unique substrings. The code below converts the set to a List as that seems to be what you want.

```
import re

my_string_list = ['AA.a','aa.b','AS.a','we.b','kk.f']

res = list({re.findall(r"\.\w+", entry)[0] for entry in my_string_list})
```

which is equivalent to:

```
s = set()
for entry in my_string_list:
    sub_str = re.findall(r"\.\w+", entry)
    s.add(sub_str[0])
 res = list(s)
```

then

```
print(res)
```

gives in both cases:

```
['.b', '.a', '.f']
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution (without `re`):

```py
strings = ['AA.a','aa.b','AS.a','we.b','kk.f']

out = {f'.{s.split(".")[-1]}' for s in strings}
print(out)  # or print(list(out)) to print as a list
```

Prints:

```
{'.a', '.b', '.f'}
```